# Call Model function from javascript in razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Is it possible to call a Model function in a razor page like this (the function is never hit):

`<input id="btnWork" type="submit" value="Work" onclick="writeLog("add to log");" />`

However, I have this in my razor page and it hits the function on page load only:

```
{
<script>
     function writeLog(msg)
     {
         @IndexModel.logHolder.Add("testing 123");
     }
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [Mike Brind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71690708/7687666). At the same time, I also did some testing work, which I also shared.

We can't call C# function from javascript directly, Because javascript execute on client side and C# function execute at server side.
So we need to call it other way like `AJAX`.

**Define your function in Model and call it via AJAX call.**

JS Code:

```
<script>
   function writeLog(msg) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '?handler=WriteLog&msg='+msg,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
          alert("Error: " + error);
        }
      })
    }
</script>
```

Model Function Code:

```
public IActionResult OnGetWriteLog(string msg)
{
    return new JsonResult(msg); 
}
```

Test Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete code? For example, you're missing the inclusion of jquery in order for the $ to work, and how are you calling the writeLog function in the cshtml?

Comment: After struggling a lot, this answer nearly solved my problems, Thanks a lot @Jason

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot call a server-side method directly from JavaScript. What you can do is to use JavaScript to make an HTTP request to a page handler method that invokes the server-side method instead. Typically, you would [use a named handler method for this](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods)

Add a simple named handler to your PageModel that responds to GET requests and takes a string as a parameter. The handler's name is **Add** i.e. the name of the method without the `OnGet`, `OnPost` part:

```
public void OnGetAdd(string msg)
{
    // processing goes here        
}
```

Then add the following to your Razor page itself:

```
<input id="btnWork" type="submit" value="Work" onclick="writeLog('add to log');" />

@section scripts{
    <script>
    function writeLog(msg){
        fetch(`?handler=Add&msg=${msg}`);
    }
    </script> 
}
```

This uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make the HTTP request, with the handler specified in the query string along with the `msg` parameter. When you click the button, you should see the breakpoint on the handler method hit, and the msg parameter is whatever you specified in the onclick event i.e. "add to log" in this example.